# Excel - Unlock cell based on another cell answer

Tags: excel, vba

I need to unlock a cell on sheet 1 with the answer from  a question on sheet 2. I have a password set on my sheet as test. I am getting the following error.

**Runtime error 1004 - Unable to set the Locked property of the Range class**

Script below:

```
  If Sheet2.Range("C98").Value = 3 Then
      ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="test"
      Me.Range("L47").Locked = False
    Else
      Me.Range("L47").Locked = True
      Me.Protect ("test")
    End If
```

Answer (score 2):

**Before you attempt to the change the locked property of a cell, make sure the sheet is unprotected.**

Comment: So do I need to have Me.Unprotect("test") before I try to unlock the cell.

Comment: Yes.....once the sheet is unprotected, cells may be either locked or unlocked.  Then re-lock the sheet.

Comment: Hi. I am still getting the same error. My script below:     If Sheet2.Range("C98") = 3 Then
        Me.Unprotect ("test")
        Range("L47").Locked = False
    Else
        Range("L47").Locked = True
        Me.Protect ("test")
    End If

Comment: Please update your original Post with the full code.

Comment: Have uodated the code above, activate the worksheet 1st.

Comment: Use: **Me.Unprotect Password:="test"**